# Fedora Arm pkg-config file not found error (armv7hl... should be armv7hnl...)

Tags: fedora, armv7, pkg-config

I'm trying to compile a cmake project on a RasberryPi with Fedora Arm 36 and in cmake I use pkg-config. It is correctly installed but I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/pkg-config: line 8: /usr/bin/armv7hnl-redhat-linux-gnueabi-pkg-config: No such file or directory
```

In the `/usr/bin` directory there is a file called `armv7hl-redhat-linux-gnueabi-pkg-config` (missing **n** in armv7h**n**l) is this a bug?

What can I do?

**Edit**

I've reinstalled `pkg-config` but still the same error.

`/usr/bin/pkg-config` is just a bash script that calls the appropriate executable and so I hard coded the one previously mentioned, I don't get an error but `pkg-config` can't find gtkmm-4.0 which is installed.